# Launch failed Input String not in correct format in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

**Launch failed. The app 'appname.iOS' could not be launched on 'iphone'. Error: error MT1006: Could not install the application** `'/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/appname.iOS/f8449af7
cc8c6a7a7be6b5f7db1a5d7e/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.3-13.3/appname.iOS.app' on the device 'Iphone':` **Input string was not in a correct format**... Please check the logs for more details.

> Target Deployment version is :8.0
>
> IPhone version : 13.3
>
> Mac version : 10.15.3
>
> Visual studio for mac version: 8.3(Preview)
>
> Visual Studio(Windows) version : 16.4.3

Xamarin.HotReload|Information|0|2020-01-30 18:45:56.6 Stopping Hot Reload session due to ExplicitlyEnded ...
Xamarin.HotReload|Information|0|2020-01-30 18:45:56.6 Stopped Hot Reload session.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.IdbClient|Error|0|Launch failed. The app 'Kefi.iOS' could not be launched on 'Kefi'. Error: error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/kenstelnetworks/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Kefi.iOS/f8449af7cc8c6a7a7be6b5f7db1a5d7e/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.3-13.3/Kefi.iOS.app' on the device 'Kefi': Input string was not in a correct format... Please check the logs for more details.
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/kenstelnetworks/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Kefi.iOS/f8449af7cc8c6a7a7be6b5f7db1a5d7e/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.3-13.3/Kefi.iOS.app' on the device 'Kefi': Input string was not in a correct format..
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Func`2[T,TResult] exitCondition, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouchProcessType processType, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Action`1[T] handleOutput) [0x00255] in <5a8b0852b6a7411f826e8afbb6a4197c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] parameters, System.Func`2[T,TResult] exitCondition, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress) [0x00088] in <5a8b0852b6a7411f826e8afbb6a4197c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.DeployAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppInfo appInfo, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.Simulator simulator, System.Boolean debugging, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Boolean forceDeploy) [0x002c0] in <5a8b0852b6a7411f826e8afbb6a4197c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.RunMTouchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message, System.Int32 port) [0x001a8] in <5a8b0852b6a7411f826e8afbb6a4197c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceWithoutAssetsAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00091] in <5a8b0852b6a7411f826e8afbb6a4197c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x0019b] in <5a8b0852b6a7411f826e8afbb6a4197c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00104] in <5a8b0852b6a7411f826e8afbb6a4197c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2[TMessage,TResult].HandleAsync (TMessage message) [0x0010e] in <f70ca157d31c4c4da9b90a95b5ac4843>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_1`2[TMessage,TResult].b__2 () [0x00084] in :0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.ReplyAsync[TRequest,TResponse] (Xamarin.Messaging.Client.IRequest`1[T] request, Xamarin.Messaging.MessagePriority priority, System.Func`1[TResult] replyFunctionAsync) [0x000c5] in :0 
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Warning|0|Client vs10492Kenst - No packet has been sent in 30 seconds. Sending Ping to Server to maintain Keep Alive
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Warning|0|Client vs10492Kenst - No packet has been sent in 30 seconds. Sending Ping to Server to maintain Keep Alive
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Warning|0|Client vs10492Kenst - No packet has been sent in 30 seconds. Sending Ping to Server to maintain Keep Alive
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Warning|0|Client vs10492Kenst - No packet has been sent in 30 seconds. Sending Ping to Server to maintain Keep Alive

Comment: Did you check the logs as it suggests?

Comment: please check logs above

Comment: I guess you need try to remove any special symbols from application name like dots (.) or something and try to launch again.

Comment: my application name is only "Kefi" there are no special symbol.

Comment: Problem not occur on simulator it only come when we deploy code on real device

Comment: You can try to delete the bin and obj folder, clean and rebuild again.

Comment: Delete obj and bin and clean and rebuild not work.

Comment: Can you please try the solutions in these links [Error MT1006 while trying to debug on iPhone](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58651/error-mt1006-while-trying-to-debug-on-iphone) and [Cannot Debug on iPhone device](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3915).

Comment: Device Reboot not worked.

Comment: Well, can you please share a sample project which can reproduce the issue?